# Migrating GCP Object storage data to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We have terabytes of Data in Google Cloud Object Storage, we want to migrate it to AWS S3. What are the best ways to do it? Is there any 3rd party tool that can be better instead of going for direct transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple options available even without using any device (cloud to cloud migration) in less time.

** gsutil to copy data from a Google Cloud Storage bucket to an Amazon bucket, using a command such as:**

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://your-gcp-bucket s3://your-aws-s3-bucket
```

More details is available @ https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

**Note:** if you face speed challenge  with default cloud shell, then you can create a big machine and execute above command from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Appreciate your input.